# how to have a web.py python webservice return a jsonp call to jquery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, jsonp, web.py

**So I'm trying to get a web.py based python webservice to send back a list object trough JSONP after jQuery makes an ajax call to it.**

Problem is after reading up a lot of examples I'm still failing to understand how to make it work. Here's the code I got I'm working with atm:

Javascript:

```
xmlrpcproxy = 'http://0.0.0.0:1885/'; //Back To The Future III reference on the port :)

jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
    url: xmlrpcproxy, // <--- returns valid json if accessed in the browser
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "jsonp", // Pay attention to the dataType/contentType
    dataType: 'jsonp', // Pay attention to the dataType/contentType
    });
jQuery.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("You made it!");
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var firstoption = '<option value="select" selected>Please Select</option>';
    jQuery("select#ItemIDSelect").html(firstoption);
    var i;
    var erplist = JSON.parse(data);
    jQuery("responsearea").append(erplist);
    for (i = 0; i < erplist.length; ++i) {
                jQuery("select#ItemIDSelect").append('<option value="' + erplist[i] + '">' + erplist[i] + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Python web.py code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# _*_ encoding: utf-8 _*_

import web
import xmlrpclib
import json

urls = (
  '/(.+)', 'index',
)


class index:
    def GET(self):
    #THE FOLLOWING IS A SUCCESFULL QUERY FOR DATA TO AN ERP SERVER
    server = '***.***.*.**' #hidden the openerp server for stackoverflow post
    username = 'admin' #the user
    pwd = 'admin'      #the password of the user
    dbname = 'demo'    #the database



    # Get the uid
    sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://%s:8069/xmlrpc/common'%(server))
    uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)

    #replace localhost with the address of the server
    sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://%s:8069/xmlrpc/object'%(server))

    # Unactive all product with a stock = 0.0 and using the ancient code

    ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'search', [])

    p_ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'read', ids, ['name'])
    #END OF THAT PARTICULAR QUERY

    a=[]
    for p in p_ids:
        a.append(p['name'])
    b = json.dumps(a)
    return 'some_function(' + b + ')
```

example: typical content of **b**

```
["The Jackson Group's Project", "Research & Development", "E-Learning Integration", "Website Design Templates", "Data Import/Export Plugin", "1", "Project XXX", "Contract Agrolait", "Project : Agrolait"]
```

Can anyone help? As I understand there is a way of setting the name of the function in the javascript side so perhaps that would be one way to solve it, setting that to some_function I mean. But all idea's/ways as how to fix this are welcome ofc, so far nothing I tried worked >.<

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery seems to provide callback function name in `callback` query param. And make sure to set correct content type header.

```
callback_name = web.input(callback='callback').callback
web.header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript') 
return '%s(%s)' % (callback_name, b)
```